# How to make a curved flight path?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to make a bullet fly in an arc when shooting and hit the player.
As in this picture . I tried to use formulas from physics, the body is thrown at an angle to the horizon, that's what came of it . But the bullet flies away into the void

```
velocity = Mathf.Round(Vector3.Distance(lastpos, transform.position) / Time.deltaTime);
lastpos = transform.position;
Vector3 direction = PlayeCar.position - Vector3.zero;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x); // радианы


float x = velocity * Mathf.Cos(angle) + gravity * (time* time) / 2;
float y = velocity * Mathf.Sin(angle);

transform.position = new Vector2(x, y)
```

;
[image]

Comment: I'd make the bullet a rigidbody. You then apply a force with a direction when the bullet is shot and the phisycs are handled for you regarding the movement.

Comment: I've already tried, you can throw off your version of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample orientative method could be (The script would be attached to the gun that shots, so when the code referes to transform, refers to the gun's transfom):

```
 public void LaunchTarget()
{
    Vector3 initialSpeed = transform.forward; //shot direction, gun's forward
    GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(m_bullet);//reference to bullet prefab

    //in case you need to randomize the shot speed
    initialSpeed = transform.forward * Random.Range(m_minLaunchSpeed, m_maxLaunchSpeed); 

    //set the initial position of the bullet in the gun
    go.transform.position = transform.position;
    // shoot (give speed to the bullets rigidbody)
    go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = initialSpeed;
    //initially disabled soas to see the bullet when shot
    go.SetActive(true);
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn’t work. The bullets don’t fly, but I assume that they will fly directly to the object and not arched . But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: "How to make a bullet fly in an arc when shooting and hit the player" es the first sentence of your question. I don't underestand what you need

Comment: Nice. Please check as answer or upvote if my approach was helpfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it !!!! at the time of the bullet’s flight, I turn it toward the player in an intermittent manner. And after a while I delete it

```
   void Start()
    {
        rigidbodyBullet = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Player = GameObject.Find("carPlayer").GetComponent<Transform>();
        _distance = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, transform.position);
        Invoke("DestroyArcBullet", 1.5f);
        limitDistance = _distance / 1.3f;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += transform.up * Time.deltaTime * 5f;
        _distance = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, transform.position);


        if (_distance < limitDistance)
        {
            var turn = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,
                Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, Player.position - transform.position), Time.deltaTime * 2);
            rigidbodyBullet.MoveRotation(turn.eulerAngles.z);
        }


        if (this.transform.position.y + this.transform.position.y <= -10 || this.transform.position.y + this.transform.position.y >= 10
            || this.transform.position.x + this.transform.position.x <= -10 || this.transform.position.x + this.transform.position.x >= 10)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```